# HLSL float4x4 individual floats

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl

Simple question, but how can I access single floats or float4's in a 4x4 matrix in HLSL?

I tried: matrix._m00_m01_m02 for a float3 to no avail.
I also tried matrix._00_01_02 to no avail.

What is the correct way to get single floats or float3/4's of a matrix in HLSL?

Also, how do I insert a float4 in a matrix?

Comment: Weird, that [should work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509634(v=vs.85).aspx#Matrix). Can you post more details, like what error you are seeing?

Comment: Additionaly: The `matrix._m00_m01_m02`should actually work, the components without an m start with index 1 (`_11`,`_12`,...) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the same accessing method as matrices in almost all languages?

```
myField[row][column] = potato;
```